# custom google map doesn't show place details in KMZ file

Tags: google-maps, kmz

I've a problem with my custom google map. It doesn't show street names .

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.753633, 13.952404), 
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        scrollwheel: true
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'), mapOptions);

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://128.199.209.42/klinkfiles/mlmsurvey.kmz'
    });

    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}       
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="google-map" class="google-map"></div>
```

Comment: You want the street names displayed on the map tiles?  Don't request the SATELLITE map type, you want HYBRID.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the street names on the map tiles, don't request the SATELLITE map type, you want HYBRID.

```
var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.753633, 13.952404), 
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        scrollwheel: true
    }
```

[image: screenshot or resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.753633, 13.952404),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    scrollwheel: true
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-map'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://128.199.209.42/klinkfiles/mlmsurvey.kmz'
  });

  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#google-map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="google-map"></div>
```